# How to configure IPIP tunnel via Netplan, including routes

Tags: networking, netplan, tunnel

I am trying to set up a IPIP tunnel in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS via Netplan config.

I managed to set up the tunnel with routes from server A to server B with those ip commands:

85.ll.ll.ll is server A

85.rr.rr.rr is server B

```
ip tunnel add tunnel-to-b mode ipip remote 85.rr.rr.rr local 85.ll.ll.ll
ip link set tunnel-to-b up
ip addr add 10.0.0.18/24 dev tunnel-to-b
ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 dev tunnel-to-b
ip route add 172.16.0.0/12 dev tunnel-to-b
ip route add 192.168.0.0/16 dev tunnel-to-b
```

but I like to have this configured with Netplan config

and have tried this out

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens7:
      addresses:
        - 10.6.170.1/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: [private.local]
      optional: false
    ens8:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
      gateway4: 85.ll.ll.1
  tunnels:
    tunnel-to-b:
      mode: ipip
      addresses:
        - 10.0.0.0/8
      local: 85.ll.ll.ll
      remote: 85.rr.r.rr
      mtu: 1480
      routes:
        - to: 10.0.0.0/8
          via: tunnel-to-b
```

and I get the following error message:

```
/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml:27:8: Error in network definition: expected sequence
       to: 10.0.0.0/8
       ^
```

The question is how to setup the tunnel with routes with Netplan?